# How to extract object from NSArray that is in Dictionary Format

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

So I have an `NSArray` returned from a `Core Data` request (in NSDictionary format) like this:

```
{
    item = "Black Pipe x21' A53";
}
```

but when I try to display it on a label in a `prototype` cell it shows up with the brackets and key. I want to extract the "item" key and display it as an `NSString` on a `label`, so the `label` just shows as "Black Pipe x21' A53".

How can you extract the text for the "item" key if its not in `NSDictionary` format? The predicate I used forced me to use the `Dictionary` format. It is in an `NSArray` object.

So confused. Any help would be appreciated. I'm new at this `Objective-C` stuff.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *value = _arrayObj[indexPath.row][@"item"];
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I just realized I can use the valueForKey method of the NSArray object to return the "item", and then I saw you d id the same thing in a cooler way. I feel so dumb. The way you did it makes it look a lot more C-ish, which is what I'm transitioning from.

Comment: And I chose yours as the answer because you did it with one line and without using an NSDictionary object or any kind of dictionary conversion. kudos

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a new to language, try simple constructs.

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in YOUR_ARRAY) {
 NSString *title = [dict valueForKey:@"item"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++) 
{
    NSDictionary *Dic =[[[NSDictionary alloc]init]autorelease];
    Dic=[array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Dic objectForKey:@"item"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  NSDictionary *dictionaryName=arrayName[0];
  NSstring *str=dictionaryName[@"item"];
```

Comment: This works too. I can't believe I didn't realize there was a valueForKey method in an array object. I thought that was just for NSDictionary objects. I would upvote you but I can't

Comment: @mannibis...dont worry it is always like this in starting phase..Now if you are clear with your doubt then you can at least upvote my answer ;)

Comment: Like I said I can't because my reputation is below 15 :( but I would if I could